# Xamarin - No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MyTheme')

Tags: android, xamarin

Using Xamarin Forms I cannot seem to get the project to build. I can build a normal Xamarin android project but it keeps failing when using Forms

My styles are defined as: 
**style.xml in values**

```
 <resources>
      <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
      </style>
      <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

**style.xml in values-21**

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">

  </style>
</resources>
```

And the following in the manifest

```
  <application android:label="AppName" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/MyTheme"></application>
```

Comment: I'm not doing anything more in my activity except for the boilerplate code initiating the shared application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in the file name. It should be`styles.xml` versus `style.xml`. You would still use `@style/MyTheme` however.

Comment: That may just be a typo in the question

Comment: Turns out this was half the problem together with values-21 needing to be values-v21. Thanks